# How to provide custom exception mappings for jax-rs endpoints in Magnolia CMS (v 5.5.6)?

Tags: java, jax-rs, magnolia

I created custom jax-rs based endpoint.

```
@Path("/test")
public class MyEndpoint<D extends EndpointDefinition>  extends AbstractEndpoint<D> {

    @Path("/dosth")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void doSth() {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

Now I want to add custom exception handling for jax-rs endpoints. I want all exceptions handling in one place, instead of try-catch in every method. Tried to add jax-rs ExceptionMapper:

```
@Provider
public class CustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

   public Response toResponse(Throwable e) {
      return Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).build();
   }
}
```

Unfortunately Magnolia doesn't use it. How can I register such mapper i Magnolia 5.5.6?

Comment: btw 5.5.6 is more than 2 years old. And 5.5.x branch is EOL. You probably want to upgrade to higher version or at least to latest maintenance version which would be 5.5.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom exception mapper should be registered in `rest-integration` JCR configuration. The node responsible for jax-rs providers is

```
config.modules.rest-integration.config.additionalProviders
```

I've overridden default exception mapper by my custom implementation and now it works.

[image]